# Extremal values for the hyperbolic function: $\frac{\sinh(x/2)}{\sinh(1/2)}$

Tags: calculus

How do I find the value of the extremal for $$\dfrac{\sinh(x/2)}{\sinh(1/2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sinh(x)$ has no extrema and diverges to $\pm \infty$ as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$. It resembles a cubic and it has no points of maxima or minima along the curve. We may just consider $\sinh(x/2)$ because the denominator is constant.

No extrema.

If you want to do it algebraically just recall that the derivative of $\sinh(x)$ is just $\cosh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the
$/2$ and the constant denominator,
you want to find extreme values
for
$\sinh(x)$.

Since
$\sinh'(x) = \cosh(x)$,
and
$\cosh(x) \ge 1$
for all real $x$,
$\sinh(x)$
has *no* extreme values.